# How to display date using x86 NASM?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

Trying to display the date and it tells me I need a coma after the operand in line 16

```
section .text
    global _start       ;must be declared for using gcc
_start:                     ;tell linker entry point
    mov edx, len    ;message length
    mov ecx, msg    ;message to write
    mov ebx, 1      ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax, 4      ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel
    mov eax, 1      ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

section .data

msg db  'Hello, world!',0xa ;our dear string
len equ $ - msg         ;length of our dear string
dt db  __DATE__ ,0xa
len2 equ $ - dt
```

Comment: `dt` is a reserved word. Use a different name. PS: you do know it will substitute the date during compilation and not runtime, right? So the program will always print the date you compiled on, not the current date when run.

Comment: Isn't it a macro for the C pre-processor? Does your **assembly** file go through the C-pre-processor somehow?   "\__DATE\__ is a preprocessor macro that expands to current date (at compile time) in the form mmm dd yyyy (e.g. "Jan 14 2012"), as a string. The \__DATE\__ macro can be used to provide information about the particular moment a binary was built."

Comment: hmm, I guess 'nasm' implements its own \__DATE\__, then..

Comment: @tum_ yes [nasm has its own](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.12.7)